# what else is in $\prod_{j=1}^n(1+q^j)$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, mp.mathematical-physics

From time to time, I run into the **finite** product $\prod_{j=1}^n(1+q^j)$. And, the more it happens, the more fascinated I've become. So, herein, I wish to get help in collecting such results. To give some perspective into what I look for, check out the below examples. First, some nomenclature: $(q)_k=(1-q)(1-q^2)\cdots(1-q^k)$ and $\binom{n}k_q=\frac{(q)_n}{(q)_k(q)_{n-k}}$.

(0) It's almost silly, but the sum of elementary functions of the specialization $\pmb{q}=(q,q^2,\dots,q^n)$:
$$e_0(\pmb{q})+e_1(\pmb{q})+\cdots+e_n(\pmb{q})=\prod_{j=1}^n(1+q^j).$$

(1) The classical $q$-binomial theorem, which results from counting restricted distinct partitions or number of weighted tilings:
$$\sum_{k=0}^nq^{\binom{k+1}2}\binom{n}k_q=\prod_{j=1}^n(1+q^j).$$

(2) I can't remember where I saw this (do you?) but 
$$\sum_{k=0}^nq^k\binom{n}k_{q^2}=\prod_{j=1}^n(1+q^j).$$

(3) The $H$-polynomial of a symplectic monoid $MSp_n$ ([see this paper, page 13](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0812.3105v1.pdf)): 
$$\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^kq^{k^2}\binom{n}k_{q^2}^2\prod_{i=1}^k(1-q^{2i})\prod_{j=1}^{n-k}(1+q^j)^2=\prod_{j=1}^{2n}(1+q^j),$$
although the authors did not seem to be aware of the RHS.

> **QUESTION.** Can you provide such formulas (in any field) with the same RHS (always a finite product) as in above, together with resources or references?

Thank you.

Comment: Big list question? Traditionally, such are made Community Wiki.

Comment: perhaps we could wait and see if this does actually generate a "big list" ...

Comment: We don't know if this will be "big". I'm with Carlo, if you don't mind Todd.

Comment: There are several questions about this or close topics on MO, under the tag "q-analogs": http://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/q-analogs

Comment: @PietroMajer: Thanks. Sure, there are millions of $q$-series, but I'm asking of a very specific target, preferable with interpretations as seen in my examples. None I checked under the tag reveals answers to our question here.

Comment: ok -- just to make sure that you have checked them (I thought some may be of interest for this question ;) )

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Up to scaling, $\prod_{j=1}^n(1+q^j)$ is the character of the principal specialization of
the spinor representation of $\mathfrak{so}(2n+1)$. This was first
explicitly stated by J. W. B. Hughes, Lie algebraic proofs of some theorems on partitions, in *Number Theory and
Algebra*, Academic Press, 1977, pp. 135--155.

Comment: Cool, up-voted.

Comment: What is this parasite on the left of the formula $\mathfrak{so}(2n+1)$ ?

Comment: It is the orthogonal Lie algebra in $2n+1$ dimensions.

Comment: In Richard's expository paper on log-concave and unimodal sequences (*Ann. New York Acad. Sci.*, 1989), he mentions that by considering the principal $\mathfrak{sl}(2)$ inside $\mathfrak{so}(2n+1)$ we can prove the unimodality of the coefficients of $\prod_{j=1}^n (1+q^j)$. See Equation (23). It seems to be very difficult to prove this unimodality result otherwise.

Comment: Proctor (*Amer. Math. Monthly* 89 (1982), 721-734) did give a more elementary proof of unimodality but his argument was "secretly" motivated by the Lie-algebraic proof. He phrased his result in terms of the rank-unimodality of a certain poset $M(n)$ whose rank generating function is $\prod_{j=1}^n (1+q^j)$.

Comment: @TimothyChow: Now that you mentioned $M(n)$, let me point out that I learned this from Stanley: the poset $M(n)$, in addition to its usual definition, is also the "greedy (weak) Bruhat order" on $\mathfrak{S}_n$. This is Exercise 187(b) in Chapter 3 of Enumerative Combinatorics, Volume 1, second edition.

Answer (score 8):

In a $2n$ dimensional vector space equipped with a symplectic form, you can look at all the Lagrangian subspaces, and this forms a subvariety of the Grassmannian $G(n,2n)$ called the *Lagrangian Grassmannian*, $\Lambda(n)$. It is a smooth projective variety which inherits a schubert cell decomposition from the Grassmannian, and lots of other Schubert calculus goodness. It's cells are indexed by strict partitions with largest part at most $n$. The number of points of $\Lambda(n)$ over finite fields is given by $\prod_{i=1}^n(1+q^i)$, so unimodality of the coefficients can be obtained from the Hard Lefschetz theorem. (Not like this is a simpler way of looking at it, but perhaps a geometric point of view can be useful for certain applications, for example the classical q-binomial theorem follows from a certain stratification of $\Lambda(n)$.)

A reference for an explicit presentation of the cohomology ring using Schur Q-polynomials can be found in "Algebro—Geometric applications of Schur S- and Q-polynomials" by Piotr Pragacz, Topics in Invariant Theory ,M. P. Malliavin Ed., Springer Lecture Notes in Math., 1478, 1991.

Answer (score 2):

Let $exp(z,q)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}z^k/[k]_q!$ be the usual  $q-$analogue of the exponential function $e^x.$
The identity
$\sum_{k=0}^n{q^k}{\binom{n}{k}_{q^2}}=\prod_{j=1}^n(1+q^j)$ 
can be obtained by comparing coefficients in 
$$exp(\frac{z}{1+q},q^2)exp(\frac{qz}{1+q},q^2)=exp(z,q),$$
which is a natural $q-$analogue of $e^\frac{x}{2} e^\frac{x}{2}=e^x.$
This identity occurs in Séminaire Lotharingien de Combinatoire, B05a (1981), but is perhaps older.